# Is there a way to access the original function in a mocked method/function such that I can modify the arguments and pass it to the original functions?

Tags: python, mocking

I'd like to modify the arguments passed to a method in a module, as opposed to replacing its return value.

I've found a way around this, but it seems like something useful and has turned into a lesson in mocking.

#### module.py

```
from third_party import ThirdPartyClass

ThirdPartyClass.do_something('foo', 'bar')
ThirdPartyClass.do_something('foo', 'baz')
```

#### tests.py

```
@mock.patch('module.ThirdPartyClass.do_something')
def test(do_something):
    # Instead of directly overriding its return value
    # I'd like to modify the arguments passed to this function.

    # change return value, no matter inputs
    do_something.return_value = 'foo'

    # change return value, based on inputs, but have no access to the original function
    do_something.side_effect = lambda x, y: y, x

    # how can I wrap do_something, so that I can modify its inputs and pass it back to the original function?
    # much like a decorator?
```

I've tried something like the following, but not only is it repetitive and ugly, it doesn't work. After some PDB introspection.. I'm wondering if it's simply due to however this third party library works, as I do see the original functions being called successfully when I drop a pdb inside the `side_effect`.

Either that, or some auto mocking magic I'm just not following that I'd love to learn about.

```
def test():
    from third_party import ThirdPartyClass
    original_do_something = ThirdPartyClass.do_something

    with mock.patch('module.ThirdPartyClass.do_something' as mocked_do_something:
        def side_effect(arg1, arg2):
            return original_do_something(arg1, 'overridden')

        mocked_do_something.side_effect = side_effect

        # execute module.py
```

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Why you say *it doesn't work*. What is the behaviour? AFAIK it should work and I used this way [more times](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30016312/4101725)... I can explain the other details but before file an answer I would like to know why the *ugly* way donsn't work as expected.

Answer (score 41):

You may want to use parameter `wraps` for the mock call. ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) for reference.) This way the original function will be called, but it will have everything from Mock interface.

So for changing parameters called to original function you may want to try it like that:

**`org.py`**:

```
def func(x):
    print(x)
```

**`main.py`**:

```
from unittest import mock

import org


of = org.func
def wrapped(a):
    of('--{}--'.format(a))


with mock.patch('org.func', wraps=wrapped):
    org.func('x')
    org.func.assert_called_with('x')
```

result:

```
 --x--
```

Comment: From all `wraps` related answers, this one is the clearest.

Comment: So how to change the parameters or to add something to the return value?

Comment: @Velkan add everything you need inside `wrapped` function. On my example I'am changing passed parameter by adding `--` on both sides of the string.

Answer (score 7):

The trick is to pass the original underlying function that you still want to access as a parameter to the function.

Eg, for race condition testing, have `tempfile.mktemp` return an *existing* pathname:

```
def mock_mktemp(*, orig_mktemp=tempfile.mktemp, **kwargs):
    """Ensure mktemp returns an existing pathname."""
    temp = orig_mktemp(**kwargs)
    open(temp, 'w').close()
    return temp
```

Above, `orig_mktemp` is evaluated when the function is *declared*, not when it is called, so all invocations will have access to the original method of `tempfile.mktemp` via `orig_mktemp`.

I used it as follows:

```
@unittest.mock.patch('tempfile.mktemp', side_effect=mock_mktemp)
def test_retry_on_existing_temp_path(self, mock_mktemp):
    # Simulate race condition: creation of temp path after tempfile.mktemp
    ...
```