# Changing decorator params in unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-decorators

I have this function I would like to test:

```
@retry(delay = 2)
def func1():
    do_something_that_might_fail()
```

When I test this func and mock a failure of `do_something_that_might_fail` the decorator waits for two seconds and then tries again. Is there a way to override the `delay` param of the decorator to make my test faster?

Comment: Also see [How to remove the effects of a decorator while testing in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32697596)

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, I just found my answer (which was patching `time.sleep`)